# What size capacitor do I need to power a 12v circuit requiring .002A for 1 second?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I am attempting to make a flashing 12v signal into a constant (ish) 12v signal by smoothing it out.  When the flasher is in its "off" phase Im needing to simualate the same as when its on.  (other options to remove the flasher are not possible)

I need to power the 12v circuit for 1 second supplying .002 amps with a capacitor.  How do I calculate the size of the capacitor needed? Assuming I need a 6000 Ohm resistor (R = 12v/.002A) with it to slow the capacitor drain during that full second that flasher relay is "off"  but I cant figure out the formula to identify how many farad capacitor is needed to bridge the "off" gap in my flasher relay circuit.

Comment: What is your voltage requirement?

Comment: Its 12v. I need a full 12v.

Comment: the problem is that the moment you no longer have a voltage source powering the capacitor, and you start draining charge from it, the voltage on the capacitor goes down. Even high-end power supplies have a spec on the allowed voltage variation under different loading conditions. If your load is a light bulb (or better, and LED), it might not be that picky about the exact voltage.

Answer (score 1):

2 mA for 1 s is 2 millicoulombs, Then it comes down to how much drop you can tolerate: if, for example, you can tolerate 4V, you have (2 mC)/(4 V)=(0.5 mF)=500 µF. I have no idea why you'd need a resistor.

It would make better sense to ask the [electrical engineering forum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). But include your actual problem. What's your power source? What's your load?